# Create own class with more than one property

Tags: c#, class, properties

i have the following class:

```
namespace Mentionfunctions
{
    class MFunctions
    {
        public bool availability(string ean)
        {
             //do
             return true;
        }
    }      
}
```

I call this one with

```
MFunctions mf = new MFunctions();
mf.availability(EAN);
```

I want to add a property to call the function with a different "mode"

I want to do something like:

```
mf.availability.global(EAN);
mf.availability.onlysupplier(EAN);
```

I googled this for ours but i'm not sure how do to that or i'm using the wrong words for searching.

Comment: Why not just... add another parameter to the method?

Comment: Create another class with properties `global` and `onlysupplier`. Then change type of `availability` property from `bool` to type of that class. And do some investigation about C# naming guidelines

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This would result in very ugly code in general, but would be kind-of-acceptable in a Fluent *configuration* API. On the other hand, classes that only contain helper functions are a code smell. Even so, you could (and should) split the functions in multiple classes

Comment: I thought that was the right way cause i wanted to it like the other classes: dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[""]....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use enums for that:

```
enum Mode
{
   global,
   onlysupplier
}

public bool availability(string ean, Mode m) { }
```

Then you can call your method like this:

```
mf.availability(EAN, Mode.global);
```

Comment: Okay this one was the right for me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a property to change the behaviour of a function.
Use an additional argument to the function instead:

```
bool availability(string ean, string mode);
```

Then make mode an Enumeration